# Clojure let vs multi-arity

Tags: java, clojure, let, arity

Thinking functional like, but in clojure, which is better, more performatic and less heavy to the JVM

```
(defn- on-message
  ([options ch {:keys [headers delivery-tag]} ^bytes payload ^CompanyProto$Company$Builder company]
   (check-id company)
   (save company options)
   (basic/ack ch delivery-tag))
  ([options ch ^PersistentHashMap kwargs ^bytes payload]
   (on-message options
               ch
               kwargs
               payload
               (-> (CompanyProto$Company/newBuilder)
                   (.mergeFrom payload)))))
```

or

```
(defn- on-message [options ch {:keys [headers delivery-tag] ^bytes payload}]
  (let [company (-> (CompanyProto$Company/newBuilder) (.mergeFrom payload))]
    (check-id company)
    (save company options)
    (basic/ack ch delivery-tag)))
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are considering the first option with multi-arity? Unless the method is called from somewhere else with both signatures, the second one (with let binding) is certainly less cluttered. I believe you also save one call in the stack, which seems like a needless hop in the multi-arity one.

Comment: @ToniVanhala I did with let first, but a friend said that let is bad and not functional (he is a erlang developer), I'm new in functional langs... the other thing that he said is that is weird that clojure is not stackless

Comment: [The "let" expression may be considered as a lambda abstraction applied to a value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_expression), so it fits fine with functional programming.

Comment: Thanks @ToniVanhala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your direct question is that there is no overhead introduced in a function call simply because that function happens to have multiple arities.  In Clojure, all function calls are compiled into a method invocation.  The exact method invoked depends on the number of arguments -- as far as the JVM is concerned, each arity is compiled as a different method.  The determination of which method to call is made at compile-time, so there is no overhead at run-time.

That being said, there is some overhead to making nested function calls.  Specifically, each call grows the call-stack by a constant amount until that call returns.  However, this overhead is minimal and unlikely to have a measurable impact on performace in this case.

> @ToniVanhala I did with let first, but a friend said that let is bad
>   and not functional (he is a erlang developer), I'm new in functional
>   langs... the other thing that he said is that is weird that clojure is
>   not stackless

This seems to be the real question.  So it's worth addressing this.

`let` is simply an expression that allows us to bind values to variables.  These bindings are immutable.  Furthermore, it's well-known that `let` can be implemented as a macro-abstraction over lambda (or, in Clojure's vocabulary, `fn`).  So there's certainly nothing about `let` that makes it "not functional".

There's also nothing "weird" or puzzling about Clojure not being stackless.  Clojure is a JVM language, and a call-stack is deeply embedded in the JVM's abstract computational model.  While there are ways to work around this (e.g., continuation-passing style), these methods either require abandoning deep JVM interop and/or paying a performance penalty.  Clojure is first and foremost a pragmatic language, and this is a pragmatic concession.

Besides, Clojure (being a Lisp) is really a language framework with which you forge the language you want.  Your language might make different trade-offs.  For example, your language might be ["stackless"](https://github.com/clojure/core.async).  Or it might have [first-class continuations](https://github.com/positronic-solutions/pulley.cps) (disclaimer:  I am the author of `pulley.cps`).  Or it might have a [completely different paradigm](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic) (i.e., logic vs functional).  But it can also be very simple.  With Clojure, you can choose what you pay for.

Ironically, your friend is right about the code not being functional.  However, it's not because of the `let`.  Rather, just about everything *except* the `let` is not functional.  For example, `(save company options)` is clearly a side-effecting operation.  That doesn't necessarily mean your code is bad, though -- even the purest functional program must, at some point, interact with the real world if it is to have any practical value.

Comment: That is a complete answer, thanks for that, I would like to know if you can show some examples, as I said I'm new at functional, and I really want to learn it, I didn't understood how save is not functional there...

Comment: @RafaelCustódio, "pure" functional programming programming is without side-effects.  If you think about it, `save` /must/ be either be side-effecting or the call is entirely superfluous and should be eliminated.  The reason for this is simple (but not necessarily immediately obvious) -- the value returned by `save` is never used.  Therefore, the call to `save` is only meaningful if it performs some side-effect (such as storing something in a database). (cont)

Comment: Again (and I can't stress this enough), I'm not saying your code is bad is any way.  In fact, I would say it looks quite reasonable -- there's no way you can write to a database without side-effects.  But it does mean your code technically isn't "functional" (in the purest sense).  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @NathanDavis, I was researching about that and I've found out that using agent/ref would be the "clojure way" when it have side-effects, I must isolate somewhere... I saw some people using component as well, I dunno if that is okey, I think it is...

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing with Java interop, set `*warn-on-reflection*` to `true`. If there are warnings, you need to eliminate it with type hints. Then you get "perfomatic and less heavy to the JVM" code.

P.S. Numerical computing with mutability, simple JVM types and non-checked overflows is the other story, if it is your case you need to check this out too.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, since I'm working with some Java classes, I will do that, but where? In Core.clj?

Comment: @RafaelCustódio, `(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)` in a source file with these functions. Also make this namespace with `(:gen-class)`.

Comment: You can write unperformant code without reflection.  Simply eliminating reflection warnings does not mean the code will perform well.  Plus, the idea of multiple arities and reflection are completely unrelated.  As a matter of interface, the declared type of all function arguments is `Object`.  Type-hints don't change that.

Comment: @NathanDavis of course you can. And yes, multiple arities is unrelated, but in order to be "less heavy to the JVM" while working with Java classes some checks need to be made. I didn't say that the code will be _most_ perfomatic and _least_ heavy.